# Unable to call vuex namespaced module action from Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a Vue component that uses Vuex with namespaced modules.

```
// Main Component

import store from './store';
import {mapState, mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex';

new Vue({

store,

computed: {
    ...mapState({
       showModal: state => state.showModal,
 }),

computed: {
   ...mapState('ModuleA', {
    a: state => state.a,
 }),
 ...mapState('ModuleB', {
   b: state => state.b,
 }),


 ...mapGetters('ModuleA', { getA: 'getA' } ),
 ...mapGetters('ModuleB', { getB: 'getB' } ),

},

methods: {
...mapActions('ModuleA', [ 'doSomeA']),
...mapActions('ModuleB', [ 'doSomeB']),

},

mounted() {
  let payLoad = { ... },
  this.doSomeA(payload); // I never see this getting dispatched
}


// Store


export default new Vuex.Store({

modules: { ModuleA, ModuleB }
...
}


// Module A 

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  actions: {
    doSomeA: ({dispatch, commit, getters, rootGetters}) => payload => { // do something with payload }
...
}
```

Since I have mapped the action from my namespaced module I am simply calling the action like normal method in my component. But somehow its not dispatching the action. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you try `doSomeA: ({dispatch, commit, getters, rootGetters}, payload) =>  { // do something with payload }` ?

Comment: Yes. I was returning a function thats why it was failing.